# How can an application get the user's location without asking?

Tags: geolocation

I'm interested in understanding how an application can get the physical location of a user without asking for it.

[ip2location](http://ip2location.com) is a way of doing this, but I'm looking for a way to have the app obtain the location without relying on ip2loc's service, something akin to how iPhone geolocation works.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Like when you want to spy on someone?

Comment: Not of course like Iphone geolocation did.